# Saving parsed html to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I print the results below with system.out.println however I want to pass the list of results into an insertdata.java class that will insert the data into a mysql database table. The results below are a small section but there are 8 columns in my table then I want it to move on to the next row if that makes sense.

```
13.0kts
ENE
0 x 0 x 0
unspecified
212230000
212230000 Cy [CY]
Unknown
unknown
5.6kts
```

rough thought so far, any idea how I can do this without php?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fishtrax", "username", "passw0rd");

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into ships values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

UPDATED SO FAR: InsertData.java

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fishtrax", "username", "passw0rd");

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into ships values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1,shipSpeed);
        ps.setString(2,shipDirect);
        ps.setString(3,shipSize);
        ps.setString(4,shipSpeed);
        ps.setString(5,mmsi);
        ps.setString(6,shipName);
        ps.setString(7,shipDest);
        ps.setString(8,shipEta);
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

fileParser.java

```
File input = new File("shipMove.txt");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, null);
        Elements tables = doc.select("table.shipInfo");
        for( Element element : tables ){
            Elements tdTags = element.select("td");
            // Iterate over all 'td' tags found
            for( Element td : tdTags ){
                // Print its text if not empty
                final String text = td.text();
                if( text.isEmpty() == false) {
                    if (td.getElementsByTag("a").first() != null) {
                        // Get the attribute value
                        String url = td.getElementsByTag("a").first().attr("href");

                        // Check for nulls here and take the substring from '=' onwards
                        String id = url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1);
                        System.out.println(id);
                        System.out.println(td.text());
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println(td.text());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. Add `ps.setxxx(1, ... )` for all 8 columns and then `ps.executeUpdate()`. Where are you struck with.

Comment: ah, okay I understand that bit, will get that written now...the part that I am stuck with mainly is passing the results to this class so it can go through it and save the data

Answer (score 0):

You can move out the PreparedStatement logic to method by passing all the input details(8 columns data) to it. Then you are done.

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by moving out the logic.  do you mean to remove the "?" and replace it with something else? 
Also the prepared statement is in another class than the one which supplies the results.  I will add it to my question so everyone can view it.